# How do I transfer a full Skyrim save from one XBox One to Another including Mods and CC content

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, xbox-one

I have Skyrim on an XBox One (original) and I just got an XBox One X.  I have it set up with several Mods and some Creation Club content.  I got the game and saves transferred but the Mods and Creation Club content did not transfer and I can't play my saved games because of the missing content.  Worse, I can't seem to even download mods new or old.  It immediately says it can't.

How can I get my Skyrim so I can continue playing from my saves with all my mods and CC content?

Answer (score 3):

Precise sequence necessary for transferring all content from an existing XBox One to a new one:

1. Using the network transfer option in the XBox One itself is the straightforward way to move the content:

   1. Go to System Settings/Backup & Transfer/Network Transfer.  You need to do this from both consoles so they can see each other.
   2. Go to the new console and select the game(s) to transfer Skyrim.  This will add it to the queue.
   3. Wait for it to complete.
2. On the old console start Skyrim and enter Mods.
3. Go into Load Order and record all the mods listed.  I found taking pictures worked great for this.
4. On the new console, start up Skyrim and attempt to load the first mod in your load order.  If you've lived a good life, it will just start loading.  However, it probably will  not because it's scrambled from the transfer. Restarting the console did not unstick it. To fix the scramble you need to (yes, this is bizarro world, but it works):

   1. On the main screen is an option to switch profiles.  Choose to switch to a guest profile.
   2. Attempt to go to the Mods menu.  Skyrim will crash to the "desktop" when you do this.
   3. Reload Skyrim
   4. Change profiles back to your non-guest profile
   5. Go into mods.  You should now be able to download mods again.
5. Load your mods in order based on what you recorded from your old saves.  If you don't do it in order you'll have to reorder your mods later so, don't make the same mistake I did.
6. This is sufficient if you have not bought anything from the creation club.  If you have, then you need to:

   1. Go into creation club
   2. Go into the "Items I've purchased"
   3. Go into each item and, for each one, select "Download".  (No idea what it downloads, as all the content is in there, but, it will flash and complete instantaneously.)

Now you should be able to finally restart your save games.  Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Thanks, does a similar process work for an xbox 360 to an xbox series x?